# Want to convert PDF files to XLS and then bring those XLS to a particular format

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf, conversion, mysql

Have some 1000+ PDF files. Want to convert those files to XLS and then bring those XLS files to a format which can be used to export XLS data to either existing or new MySQL tables.

Can this be automated through any scripting language?

Answer (score 0):

Link: http://www.investintech.com/products/developer/commandlinetools/pdftoexcel/
Then use batch for scripting

Read this: [Importing excel data in to mysql table using command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939550/importing-excel-data-in-to-mysql-table-using-command-line)